# Delphi XE2: Adding an HTML comment to a TWebbrowser document?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, twebbrowser, html

I use this routine to add HTML to a TWebbrowser document:

```
procedure WBAppendHTML(WB: SHDocVw.TWebbrowser; const HTML: string);
(*Appends the given HTML to the end of the given web browser control's current document body.
Does nothing if no document is loaded, if the document does not support the DOM, or if the document is a frameset.*)
var
  Doc: MSHTML.IHTMLDocument2;
  BodyElem: MSHTML.IHTMLBodyElement;
  Range: MSHTML.IHTMLTxtRange;
begin
  if not System.SysUtils.Supports(WB.Document, MSHTML.IHTMLDocument2, Doc) then
    EXIT;
  if not System.SysUtils.Supports(Doc.body, MSHTML.IHTMLBodyElement, BodyElem) then
    EXIT;
  Range := BodyElem.createTextRange;
  Range.collapse(False);
  Range.pasteHTML(HTML);
end;
```

This works when the HTML is something like this: '**My text**':

```
WBAppendHTML(wb, '<B>My text</B>');
```

But it does not work with an HTML comment:

```
WBAppendHTML(wb, '<!-- {93706302-FC6C-43D6-8362-DE71550AD998} -->');
```

Why this does not work?
So how can I add an HTML comment to the TWebbrowser document?

**EDIT 201306142055:**

To better understand how I test whether the comment was added: After trying to append the comment with WBAppendHTML, I copy the document to the clipboard:

```
// select the entire document:
wb.ExecWB(OLECMDID_SELECTALL,      OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT);
// copy the text to Clipboard:
wb.ExecWB(OLECMDID_COPY,           OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT);
// clear the selection:
wb.ExecWB(OLECMDID_CLEARSELECTION, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER);
```

After that I retrieve the HTML source from the CF_HTML part of the clipboard content:

```
function GetClipboardAsHTMLSource: string;
var
  Data: THandle;
  Ptr: PAnsiChar; // PChar;
begin
  Result := '';  
  Clipboard.Open;
  try
    Data := Clipboard.GetAsHandle(CF_HTML);
    if Data <> 0 then
    begin
      Ptr := PAnsiChar(GlobalLock(Data));
      if Ptr <> nil then
      begin
        try
          Result := UTF8Decode(Ptr);
        finally
          GlobalUnlock(Data);
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    Clipboard.Close;
  end;  
end;
```

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: Good question ;-)
After adding the HTML to the TWebbrowser document, I do a clipboard copy:
`wb.ExecWB(OLECMDID_SELECTALL, OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT);
wb.ExecWB(OLECMDID_COPY, OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT);
wb.ExecWB(OLECMDID_CLEARSELECTION, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER);`
Then I extract the CF_HTML part of the clipboard. As I said, this works with ordinary HTML code, but not with an HTML comment.

Comment: Does clipboard copy ever exports HTML comments? I mean do you see comments there if they present in the initial HTML? (Probably SELECTALL&COPY writes only visible parts of the document into the clipboard.)

Comment: Yes, it does. I just created an HTML file with this body content: `This is a test <!-- My Comment --> This is test 2`.  After opening it in MSIE I selected "This is a test This is test 2" and Ctr-C copied the selection to the clipboard. Then the extracted CF_HTML part of the clipboard content contained the "<!-- My Comment -->" comment.

Comment: Well, sorry, I'm lost here. Maybe PasteHTML just doesn't recognize the HTML comment. I would try setting `htmlText` property of the Range, maybe it skips some additional parsing.

Comment: `Range.htmlText` is Read-Only.

Comment: Have you tried with insertAdjacentHTML? It should be defined by MSHTML. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752300(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: Where do you use "WB" in the function `WBAppendHTML(WB: SHDocVw.TWebbrowser;...)` ? We can not see !

Comment: @moskito-x In the first line: `System.SysUtils.Supports` first returns Doc Interface, then in the second line it returns BodyElem interface, etc. See Delphi documentation about `System.SysUtils.Supports`.

Comment: @StijnSanders I've also tried `insertAdjacentHTML` - it's the same story as with `Range.pasteHTML`: Both don't like HTML comments and both don't like empty tag pairs (where I tried to stick the GUID inside an attribute value). They just omit HTML comments and empty tag pairs. Strange!